# Classification models: finding name for specific loss function

Tags: classification, loss-functions, precision-recall

Below is the linear classifier analogy, where the two lines are the decision boundaries with different thresholds that gives 0 false positive and 0 false negative respectively. A, B, C are sets of data points in the regions determined by the decision boundaries.

I want to find the classifier that minimizes $\dfrac{|B|}{|A|+|B|+|C|}$, where $|A|$ and $|C|$ are "pure" sets.

Is there a specific name for it?

[image]

Comment: Could you explain your notation and figure a little bit more? If you care about proportion of correct classifications, it's accuracy.

Comment: Yes, sorry that I wasn't clear before.

Comment: Do the lines have to be parallel, as shown in the diagram?

Comment: Yes. In the linear case, I'm trying to find the family of parallel lines with the gradient such that |B| is the minimum.